# Я написал бота, но через некоторое время он вылетает. Как можно сделать его перезапуск?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Я написал бота на питоне, он вылетает через рандомное время, иногда это 5 мин, иногда это больше 8ч. Чаще всего проблема с api, но бывает и просто прерывание соединения, a как сделать его перезапуск я не знаю. `try/except` не особо помогает.

vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] иногда её (сейчас вылетел с ней)
Read timed out. (read timeout=35) иногда с ней

```
vk_sesion = vk_api.VkApi(token="***************")

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_sesion, ***********)



def command():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.from_chat:
                id = event.chat_id
                msg = event.object.message["text"].lower()
                time.sleep(1)
                if msg == "!деж":
                    dej = random.sample(s_name, 2)
                    sender(id, str("Дежурные: " + dej[0] + " и " + dej[1]))
                    print(dej)
                if msg == "!зам":
                    if not zam:
                        sender(id, "замен нет")
                    else:
                        sender(id, zam)
                    print(zam)


while True:
    try:
        command()
    except:
        command()
```

Comment: Какие ошибки возникают? Добавьте трассу стека в вопрос через [edit]

Comment: `vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100]` это не трасса стека :) В `except` уберите вызов `command` и добавьте `print(traceback.format_exc())` в начале скрипта импортируйте `traceback`: `import traceback`. Это даст возможность увидеть в консоли трассу стека. Еще... погуглите что означает ошибка 100 для API вк, мб поймете что делаете не так

Answer (score 1):

Лучше разобраться, что за ошибка и обрабатывать именно её.
В любом случае в коде выше можно пропускать ошибки, если немного изменить главный цикл:

```
while True:
    try:
        command()
    except Exception:
        continue
```